# Who are the Revelers?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It’s the three Reveller’s on the bridge next to the Half-Moon Mill?
I have noticed them every time I pass the mill and have finished most quests now without finding a reason for them being there.
 Sometime one will offer me a drink other times they don’t have much to say at all.
Is there a reason for them being there have I missed something or are they just scenery?

Answer (score 4):

The Wiki should clear your question

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Reveler

http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Reveler

> The Revelers are three happily-intoxicated Nord farmers you may meet
>   at random locations while traveling the roads of Skyrim. All three
>   wear random farm clothes, carry two bottles of Honningbrew Mead, and
>   immediately invite you to join the party.

Seems that there is a mini-quest that rewards you with a Charmed Necklace (it's explained in the wiki, so I won't excerpt it).